# Is this JavaScript injection (DOM-based) real or false positive?

Tags: javascript, dom, eval, penetration-testing

I'm trying to grasp JavaScript DOM-based injection attacks better, so I would appreciate some input on this.

I have this output from Burpsuite as "firm" indicating it should be something here.
So the the main page loads a .js file with the code below.
Data is read from document.location and passed to eval() via the following statements:

```
var _9f=document.location.toString();
var _a0=_9f.split("?",2);
var _a1=_a0[1];
var _a2=_a1.split("&");
var sp=_a2[x].split("=");
djConfig[opt]=eval(sp[1]);
```

If I understand this correctly, it gets the content after '?' in the url, then splits the parameters after '=' and then evals the second array of that. So www.domain.tld?first=nothing&second=**payload**, is that correct?

Given that it's already inside of a js file, I'd assume I don't need the < script >  tags in the payload? I really can't get it to fire anything so I'm doing it wrong obviously. Would appreciated some input to understand this better, not just a code snippet but some explanation would be great.

Comment: What is your `x`?

Comment: Why have this code? Why have it doing `eval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...it gets the content after '?' in the url, then splits the parameters after '=' and then evals the second array of that...

Almost. It gets the part of the string after the first `?`, splits that into an array of parameters (by splitting on `&`), then gets the value of the `x`th parameter (the one at index `x`), splits it to get its value, and `eval`s that.

This means the page executes code entered into it via the query string, which means Mary can give Joe a URL with code in it that will then execute within the page when Joe opens it, which is a potential security risk for Joe.

Say `x` is `2`. This URL would show an alert: `http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=alert(42)`

```js
var x = 2;
var _9f="http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=alert(42)";
var _a0=_9f.split("?",2);
var _a1=_a0[1];
var _a2=_a1.split("&");
var sp=_a2[x].split("=");
/*djConfig[opt]=*/eval(sp[1]);
```

Here's an example on JSBin: [`https://output.jsbin.com/cibusixeqe?a=1&b=2&c=alert(42)`](https://output.jsbin.com/cibusixeqe?a=1&b=2&c=alert(42))

How big a risk it is depends on what page this code is in.

Since the code doesn't use `decodeURIComponent` there are limits on what the code in the query string can be, though they can probably be worked around...

Comment: backticks are not encoded, so `alert(\`hi\`)` should do.

Comment: @Kaiido - I had that in there for a while, but so many things kept encoding them anyway I gave up and just stuck with a number. :-)

Comment: Ah thanks for the great answer! It makes sense and of course your example on jsbin works. Perhaps it would be a completely new question, but what about the djConfig[opt] part? I can't get it to fire on my end so obviously that part is not triggering the eval.

Comment: @user13108231 - That would *receive* the result of the `eval`, setting the property whose name is in the `opt` variable on the `djConfig` variable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So the eval will run, but the result might not be visible to me?

Comment: @user13108231 - If you don't look at the `djConfig[opt]` property, no, there's no guarantee that the code being run performs any other kind of output. (In fact, I suspect it doesn't. It's not at all clear what this `eval` is for, and it's likely an example of someone having used the wrong tool.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers for the original and follow-up questions, greatly appreciated.